Disappearing candles in MT5 python trade bot
i am trying to build a fx trade bot using python and MT5 integration , below is a simplified version of my fetching logic. But i suffer from missing candles such as i turn on bot on 14:30 in a 15-min timeframe and bot updates the frame every ten seconds but after a  while bot starts to miss some candles , the printed result is something like this , it strips some of the candles randomly thus ema calculations are being wrong  , what should i do ?
historical_data_chf = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos("USDCHF", mt_timeframe, 0, 100)
histor_frame_chf = pd.DataFrame(historical_data_chf)        
while True:
    try:
        last_candle_chf = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos("USDCHF", mt_timeframe, 0, 1)
        last_frame = pd.Dataframe(last_candle_chf)
        updated_frame = pd.concat(last_frame , histor_frame_chf)
        print(updated_frame_chf.tail())

        print(f"Seconds until next candle: {seconds_until_next_candle}")

        time.sleep(10)

2024-09-20 10:45:00  0.84706  0.84808  0.84692  0.84792         2330       0            0         0.846639   0.000099             0  0.847360      1          0
2024-09-20 11:00:00  0.84793  0.84807  0.84744  0.84783         2243       0            0         0.846745   0.000105             0  0.847595      1          0
2024-09-20 11:15:00  0.84784  0.84811  0.84760  0.84769         2230       0            0         0.846837   0.000092             0  0.847642      1          0
2024-09-20 11:30:00  0.84768  0.84771  0.84710  0.84732         1772       1            0         0.846895   0.000058             0  0.847481      1          0
2024-09-20 12:45:00  0.84735  0.84744  0.84730  0.84743           40       1            0         0.846947   0.000052             0  0.847456   

I have tried to correlate the timeframe between computer and metatrader5 , succesfully done but it is not effective, mt5 is updated to last version, i am using python 3.11.
